# Powershell Certificate Import From RootCA

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ssl-certificate

With the GUI I just use MMC \ Certificates and do an import and point to my AD integrated certificate for ldaps, how can i accomplish this with powershell

I am trying this to no avail

```
Get-Certificate -Template ldaps -CertStoreLocation cert:\localmachine\MY -Credential $cred -Url http://rootca/certsrv
```

Error:

```
Get-Certificate : CX509EnrollmentPolicyWebService::Initialize: The parameter is incorrect. 0x80070057 (WIN32: 87 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER). This may be the result of user credentials being required on the remote machine. See Enable-WSManCredSSP Cmdlet help on
how to enable and use CredSSP for delegation with PowerShell remoting.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Certificate -Template Computerv2 -CertStoreLocation cert:\localma ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Certificate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemotingFailure,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.GetCertificateCommand
```

Comment: Can you update your question with any error details? "I am trying this to no avail" doesn't tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: You usually "do an import" _of what_? Are you trying to make the local machine trust the CA?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the rootca certificate is already on the server, I am just trying to import  a specific certificate with the template name ldaps

Comment: @BendertheGreatest error updated, I have tried enabling ssp to no avail, I guess my question is, if you have an ADDS integrated Certificate template, how via powershell do i import that?  The steps I would take via the gui were mmc \ certificates \ Local machine \Personal > import, and I would get to a screen that showed me all the templates a specific server was granted access to and I would just select the template and enroll.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This actually got me going "certreq -enroll -machine -q "LDAPS_CERTIFICATE", would love to know the powershell equivalent of that command if you know it

Answer (score 0):

certreq -enroll -machine -q "LDAPS_CERTIFICATE"